# Modify the script to export only visible rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am using below script for export data to excel. It's exporting all the available data in Table. I want to modify in such a way that it can only export visible rows. Also I want to add some more columns/informations to the table to be downloaded.

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {

    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
       , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
       , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
       , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(table, name,filename) {
         if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById("testTable");    
             var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
             document.getElementById("dlink").href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
             document.getElementById("dlink").download = filename;
             document.getElementById("dlink").click();
        }
});
```

am using $('[style*="display: none"]').remove(); for removing hidden columns. but it also removes data from table. I want to get this remove from only exported data. and want to add some more information in exported sheet.

Any input/suggestion from any of you will be appreciated.